# Weird UV maps and textures not aligning

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have the issue that when I uv unwrap a cone, like the nosecone of a rocket, the pieces are not aligned in the uv map and the textures don't align. Does anybody know how to fix this? Here is a picture:

[image]

[image: How do I make the globe into something like the picture?]

Comment: Hello :). Please add your texture and UV map, to better illustrate the question. Thanks.

Comment: ohh sorry, I did add a picture, but I think something went wrong

Comment: No problem, fixed that for you :).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WdRTahK, here is another picture of the texture on the model and what I mean with the weird shifted texture

Comment: Hey :). You can edit the question and add the new image there, so it's visible.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:**

Just don't use that many seams and the texture will align better.

I added seams only to cut off the side 'wings', and the rest is just one piece.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the anwser, but it doesn't work with my model, I will add another picture of the model, so you can see why it doesn't work

Comment: because it has little flaps to the side, like here https://imgur.com/a/Zl3R3xv

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: Sure, you can always unwrap manually :). Just don't use that many seams.

Comment: Ok thank you. :)

Comment: Hey :). That never happened to me. Please ask it as a new question, I have no idea what it could be :). I'm sure someone elese will help.

Comment: I fixed it already, I just need to get the texture aligned now thank you :)